# What are the best remote guerrilla research/test methods to get feedback from app users in Europe?

Tags: user-research, usability-testing

I’m a UX Team of one based in Asia but the primary market for our apps is Europe. We have slow uptakes for our apps in certain markets and really need user feedback as to why, but unfortunately we can’t afford subscriptions to enterprise tools such as Userzoom etc.

What are some Guerrilla methods I can use to get feedback about our product and research user needs? Primarily I'd like to conduct usability testing and interviews to see why users don't like the app, or what specifically is not working for people in Germany – on a budget.

I can't travel so these would have to be remote methods.

Comment: This is a very vague question, you would need to elaborate on what challenges you are facing so that people can help you.

Comment: Welcome to the site @Jamie!  At the moment, your post is a request for a list.  Lists aren't a very good fit for a Q&A site because it's hard to vote a single "best" answer to the top.  If you can give some more information about the specific problem you're facing, people can answer with a possible better approach you might use. What have you tried? What problems are you encountering? Are there any particular limitations to recruiting your target users? What stage of development is your product in? What type of questions are you hoping to answer with the research?

Answer (score 1):

Double edged sword I'm afraid, guerilla testing is great for UX practitioners with little or no budget, but is exceptionally poor when trying to recruit and brief participants, given your remote location I think you're going to really struggle.

Remote surveys could work for you on a cost & (again) remote level, engagement is still an issue.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I think surveys would at least give us something :) I have a vague idea about recruiting users via social media to get various feedback about the app.